# Paypal membership system payment dates

Tags: paypal, payment, subscribe

On the paypal subscribe button there are only 4 options for payments, daily, weekly, monthly and annually. Is there no way I could implement a payment system for every 3 months or 6 months?

Answer (score 1):

You must use a custom html form, and set manually parameters "p3" and "t3". Following this example:

```
<form method="post" name="formName" id="submitThisForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="your@papypamail.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Your Membership" />
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="0.01">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="SECURITYCODE" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="page going after payment" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="ITEM DESCRIPTION" />
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="your_listener_file.php" />
```

The allowable range for parameter "p3" is 1 to 24.

**In your case must set**

```
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="3">
```

**AND**

```
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="6">
```

Comment: Anyway to do this with a drop down menu?

Comment: Yes, not a problem to do this with javascript